# How to make QGIS show raster image with correct axis scale? NOT SQUARE!

Tags: qgis, raster

I've loaded two .IMG raster files from USGS into QGIS. The IMG files themselves are perfect squares of about 10,800x10,800 pixels at 10meter resolution.

But in reality, the terrain they represent is NOT square because the pixel scale is 8 meters for xScale and 10 meters for yScale.

This is confusing because QGIS is displaying the images such that they *look* perfectly square. How can I make QGIS scale the image in each axis independently so that I get a true visual representation of the map/terrain proportions?

Comment: Most GIS raster data sets have sufficient information to pin the corners of the data to the correct points so that the raster cells do have the right shape. Does your data appear in the right place on the earth? Or is there no coordinate data at all and it appears with a lower left coordinate of 0,0 and an upper of 10800,10800? Do you need to georeference it properly?

Comment: Can you post your raster's metadata ? It might help us understand what's going on.